# Consider $S = \left\{1,2,3,4\right\},$ Subsets $A,B$ and $C$ are formed, Probability that $A\cup B=S$ and $n(A\cap B)=3,$ is

Tags: probability

> Consider $S = \left\{1,2,3,4\right\},$ Subsets $A,B$ and $C$ are formed,
>
> $(1)\;$ Then probability that $A \cap B\cap C = \phi,$ is
>
> $(2)\;$ Then Probability that $n(A\cap B)=2,$ is
>
> $(3)\;$ Probability  that $A\cup B=S$ and $n(A\cap B)=3,$ is
>
> $(4)\;$  Probability  that $n(A)>n(B)>n(C)\geq 1,$ is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ For $(1)$ Given $A,B,C$ be the subset of $S$ Now Let $a$ be an element

which belongs to $A,B,C$ or not belongs to $A,B,C$. So we will form different cases

$\bullet\; $ If $a\in A\;,$ Then $a\in B$ and $a\in C$

$\bullet\; $ If $a\in A\;,$ Then $a\in B$ and $a\notin C$

$\bullet\; $ If $a\in A\;,$ Then $a\notin B$ and $a\in C$

$\bullet\; $ If $a\in A\;,$ Then $a\notin B$ and $a\notin C$

$\bullet\; $ If $a\notin A\;,$ Then $a\in B$ and $a\in C$

$\bullet\; $ If $a\notin A\;,$ Then $a\in B$ and $a\notin C$

$\bullet\; $ If $a\notin A\;,$ Then $a\notin B$ and $a\in C$

$\bullet\; $ If $a\notin A\;,$ Then $a\notin B$ and $a\notin C$

So Here $A\cup B\cup C=\phi$ in $7$ cases.

So the probability that $A\cup B\cup C=\phi$ is $\displaystyle \frac{7^4}{8^4}$

Now how can i solve $(2)\;,(3)$ and $(4)$ part, Help me

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you phrased your cases as "if-then" statements, because they shouldn't be.  "if $a\in A, a\in B,$ and $a\in C$."  You also used unions where you should have used intersections at the end.  Despite this, I agree that answer to (1) should be $(\frac{7}{8})^4$.  For (2), pick what the two common elements are, and then for the remaining two elements, pick how they are or aren't distributed: either in $A$, in $B$, or in neither.

Comment: For (c), note that inclusion-exclusion will imply that one of $A$ or $B$ will be equal to $S$ and the other will be a three-element set.  (If both $A$ and $B$ were three element sets, either intersection is too small or union isn't big enough.  Similarly for other cases).  Pick which is the three-element set and pick which is the missing element.